# Lock map and vector from accessing from two threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

I have two threads, each of which has a function that manipulates the same std:map and std:vector variables.

What is the best way to keep these variables.

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Also, there are lot of useful classes in the standards library [thread support](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).

Comment: It would also help to tell about what system and libraries you are using.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the kind of manipulations. Do you only overwrite the stored values, or do you also insert / remove elements? In the former case you could lock only a specific element of the container (e.g. by embedding a `std::mutex` inside each element), whereas in the latter case you need to lock the entire container during each manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal best way. You need to sanitize all read/write calls to your synchronized structure through one functions that locks/unlocks mutex accordingly. You might have multiple functions but they should all operate on the same common mutex.

Its better to have a storage class and keep the map and vector as private member variables. and write forwarding functions in that class that locks/unlocks the mutex and forwards the read/write call to actual map or vector. then you have limited number of doors to access actual structures. and it will be easier to manage.

You may use `boost::mutex` as member variable of that class.